# PowerBi Api - How to get GroupId and DatasetId of Dashboard via API

Tags: powerbi

I have been reading https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/

In this post, it mentions "To get the group ID and dataset ID, you can make a separate API call".

Does anybody know how to do this from the dashboard URL, or do I have to embed the group id and dataset id in my app alongside the dashboard URL???

Comment: My best idea so far is that the group id is the workspace id, so I already have that in my app. To get the dataset id, I read all datasets for the group into a dictionary and then when I read the report using the report id I have in my app, I can find a dataset with the same name as the report and I have the dataset id. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

> To get the group ID and dataset ID, you can make a separate API call.

This sentence isn't related to a dashboard, because in one dashboard you can put visuals showing data from many different datasets. These different API calls are [Get Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/getgroups) (to get list of groups, find the one you want and read it's id) and [Get Datasets In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdatasetsingroup) (to find the dataset you are looking for and read it's id).

But you should already know the groupId anyway, because the dashboard is in the same group.

Eventually, you can get datasetId from particular tile using [Get Tiles In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/gettilesingroup), but I do not know a way to list tiles in dashboard using the Rest API.

Comment: I think this is the answer because your link Get Tiles in Group allows the dashboard id to be specified. Also if its a report instead of a dashboard, you can use GetReport in the Api to directly get the datasetId from that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a C# project code to get the dataset id from Power BI.

Use the below method to call the 'Get' API and fetch you the dataset Id.

```
     public void GetDatasetDetails()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            HttpContent responseContent = null;
            string strContent = "";

            PowerBIDataset ds = null;         



            string serviceURL = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/datasets";


            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("- Retrieving data from: " + serviceURL);

            response = client.GetAsync(serviceURL).Result;


            Console.WriteLine("   - Response code received: " + response.StatusCode);


            try
            {
                responseContent = response.Content;
                strContent = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (strContent.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   - De-serializing DataSet details...");

                    // Parse the JSON string into objects and store in DataTable
                    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    js.MaxJsonLength = 2147483647;  // Set the maximum json document size to the max
                    ds = js.Deserialize<PowerBIDataset>(strContent);

                    if (ds != null)
                    {
                        if (ds.value != null)
                        {

                            foreach (PowerBIDatasetValue item in ds.value)
                            {
                                string datasetID = "";
                                string datasetName = "";
                                string datasetWeburl = "";



                                if (item.id != null)
                                {
                                    datasetID = item.id;
                                }

                                if (item.name != null)
                                {
                                    datasetName = item.name;
                                }

                                if (item.qnaEmbedURL != null)
                                {
                                    datasetWeburl = item.qnaEmbedURL;
                                }


                                // Output the dataset Data
                                Console.WriteLine("");
                                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                Console.WriteLine("");
                                Console.WriteLine("Dataset ID: " + datasetID);
                                Console.WriteLine("Dataset Name: " + datasetName);
                                Console.WriteLine("Dataset Web Url: " + datasetWeburl);


                            } // foreach
                        } // ds.value
                    } // ds

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   - No content received.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("   - API Access Error: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

points to remember:

1. Make sure these classes exist in your project

PowerBIDataset is a class with List
PowerBIDatasetValue is a class with id, name and webUrl (all string data type) data members

2. provide below constants in your project class

const string ApplicationID = "747d78cd-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"; 
// Native Azure AD App ClientID  --  Put your Client ID here

const string UserName = "user2@xxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
// Put your Active Directory / Power BI Username here (note this is not a secure place to store this!)

const string Password = "xyxxyx";
// Put your Active Directory / Power BI Password here (note this is not secure pace to store this!  this is a sample only)

3. call this GetDatasetDetails() method in the Main method of your project class
4. and finally

use the below 'Get' API to get the Group Id

https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups